# Clever way to square a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How do you square a matrix $A$? Do you use any clever way to do it (i.e not using the standard matrix multiplication)? It can be useful 'considering' $A$ like a linear application?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an interesting way of looking at matrix powers that circumvents the usual multiplication algorithm.  Consider the $3 \times 3$ example $A = (a_{ij})_{i,j=1}^3$.  Denote $A^2 = B = (b_{ij})_{i,j=1}^3$.  We can figure out what $b_{ij}$ is by considering all possible "paths" of length $2$ from $i$ to $j$.

That is, suppose we have a graph with $1,2,$ and $3$ and edges between each pair of numbers.  In order to get from $2$ to $3$ in $2$ moves, we can follow the paths $2\to 1 \to 3, 2 \to 2 \to 3$, and $2 \to 3 \to 3$.  So, we'll have
$$
b_{23} = a_{21}a_{13} + a_{22}a_{23} + a_{23}a_{33}
$$
In order to find the $n$-th power of a matrix, consider the paths that take $n$ "moves".

Comment: Unfortunately, for the case $n=2$ that the OP asked about, this is just the usual matrix multiplication algorithm, which the OP explicitly wanted to avoid.